# Clunking noise when braking

Tags: noise, vw

Hi so I have a 2000 VW Beetle. I've noticed recently when I have been braking with the clutch pushed in, it makes a clunk noise, sometimes multiple clunks at a time. It also makes this noise when I start off from a stop as well. My dad just replaced both control arms and the tie rods, because it was doing this before. It stopped for a while after he replaced those parts, but now it's happening again. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: When the problem is resolved, I would appreciate it if you posted what was done.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Several things that can be checked:

Pads moving in calipers - can cause a clunking noise but not usually too loud

Loose wheel nuts - may also get vibration when driving

Suspension joints failed - these can fail (prematurely) if the final tightening was done before the weight of the car was back on the wheels

Answer (score 1):

That model VW has front wheel drive and with that comes constant velocity joints. Your car is old enough to have some wear in those joints which can cause clunking noise. Usually such sounds happen when turning rather than starting or stopping, but it's definitely something to have checked.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer to single or multiple clunks on braking is a worn or missing spring clip on the brake pad /pads. The cylinder holds the pad against the disc/drum which clunks it against the caliper/ endstop once or repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but my daughter had the clunking noise when braking, but not everytime. I replaced lower control arms and struts, still no fix. Ended up being a bad passenger side axle cv.